# Is it possible to get the share count for a Page post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to collect stats on posts published to a Facebook Page. Right now I am able to track the number of comments and likes on a post easily, but shares are eluding me, and I'm wondering if it's even possible yet.

I have checked both the Graph API and the FQL tables and have not been able to find an obvious solution. The graph endpoint "/[PAGE_ID]/feed", as well as the endpoint for a post itself shows comments and likes quite plainly, but nothing about shares. Furthermore, the (undocumented?) endpoint "/[PAGE_ID]_[POST_ID]/insights" provides some fairly mysterious data about post "clicks", but nothing about shares. Finally, the FQL "stream" table again plainly provides data about comments and likes, but not about shares.

It's quite a conspicuous piece of data to be missing, as the share counts for a Page's posts would make for a really interesting, useful metric in third-party social media management software...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Available for a Page post and how ever it comes under the insights section. This is the sample url to accomplish the work. Hope this is work and  you mush have the necessary permissions and a valid access token.

```
 read_insights  : Provides read access to the Insights data for pages, applications, and domains the user owns.
```

this URL will return a json object which contains number of likes, comments , shares for your post. filter the json and you can get shares.

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/[pageid_postid]/insights/post_stories&access_token=[access_token]
```

Hopes this will helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can now access the share count for a post. ie:

```
"shares": {
        "count": 1565
      },
```

Comment: Really? That would be great. What's the actual Graph URL for this? /[PAGE_ID]_[POST_ID] ?

Comment: Can you tell us the url to retrieve the share counts please

Comment: /[PAGE_ID]_[POST_ID] url works but "read_stream" permission is required

Answer (score 0):

Now it's available via insights section

Comment: Its available via insights section