# Accessing the number of likes in shares of an image from a Facebook page

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Okay so what I'm looking for is very specific:

I'm trying to access the number of likes, on each share, of an image that is on a facebook page.

In an attempt to draw a relationship of the data I'm trying to access:
[user]-[facebook page (admin)]-[photo]-[page fan]-[shares the photo]-**[receives likes on the share]**

**Bold** is the final number of likes I'm trying to reach, not the photo likes. Though managing to get the *number of shares on the photo is half way to it*.

To further highlight the exact data I'm trying to target, here's a screenshot of it in the built in Facebook page insight https://www.dropbox.com/s/q65c5qsd62qzy0z/Screenshot%202013-10-23%2021.18.57.jpg

The data is accessible if you navigate to the insights of a page you manage, click on the post and then click on the "## shares" under it.

**So my question, is it even possible to access this data?**

**Can FB Graph Explorer provide a JSON response of it?**

Any help that would even get me closer is appreciated!

**What I tried so far:**
*First Challenge*
*Access the needed data*
This seems like the closest thing to what I'm trying to do
[Is it possible to get the share count for a Page post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102967/is-it-possible-to-get-the-share-count-for-a-page-post)
What I did is try to access the image through [pageid_postid], using the read_insight permission with an access token for the page as instructed by the Facebook documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

I've gotten a page access token by doing: using the Graph API Explorer, generate a user access token for manage_pages and read_insights, then issue /[user_id]/accounts in the Graph API prompt, which responds with a list of pages under the account with their access tokens, then click the page ID, insert the page access token in the access token field, and query for [page_id]/insights. (source: [Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages))

I still can't seem to manage to get to the number of shares, of a photo..
Some of the many GET queries I've tried..

```
/[page_id]_[post_id]/insights
/[page_id]_[post_id]/insights/post_stories
/[page_id]_[post_id]/insights/shares
```

I've also tried some old FQL methods I found around stackoverflow

More info:
I've pretty much taken this as challenge to and would like to see if it's achievable, the number of shares is expected to rise by folds in the next few days so having written a handy javascript for it would be extremely time-saving. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've just added that to the original question!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how is it done in javascript but you can get the number of likes on any post using the graph.facebook.com/postid/likes and add a parameter summary with a value 1. If I understand correctly your question.

Comment: That works fine for likes and comments, but shares are a whole other battle

Comment: Well then I think you should reframe your question, you're asking the number of likes mate

Comment: Please read the full question, not the first 5 words. I even added further explanation in the second line to avoid this confusion. All that's left is ASCII art diagram to explain it..